# Cannot create user with XML-RPC interface: No such handler: Default.setUser

Tags: xml-rpc, exist-db

I checked the documentation on the XML-RPC interface [here](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_xmlrpc.xml). The documentation mentions this method for adding new users:

```
boolean setUser(String name, String passwd, String digestPasswd, Vector groups)
```

Using [`eulexistdb`](https://github.com/emory-libraries/eulexistdb) to connect to my eXist instance, I run:

```
import os

from eulexistdb.db import ExistDB

password = os.environ["PASS"]
db = ExistDB("http://localhost:8088/", "admin",
             password, timeout=None, keep_alive=True)
db.server.setUser("foo", "foo", "", [])
```

But this leads to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    db.server.setUser("foo", "foo", "", [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/home/ldd/Documents/mangalam/btw/software/btw/.btw-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eulexistdb/db.py", line 823, in request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "/home/ldd/Documents/mangalam/btw/software/btw/.btw-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eulexistdb/db.py", line 832, in parse_response
    return unmarshaller.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 800, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 0: 'No such handler: Default.setUser'>
```

I know the connection to the server works because I am able to use `createCollection` which is also documented on the same page.

I'm using version 2.2 of eXist.

Answer (score 1):

**eXist-db's documentation is wrong.**

`setUser` is not a function supported by version 2.2. For a better list of what calls are supported, take a look at the javadoc for [`RpcApi`](http://exist-db.org/api/org/exist/xmlrpc/RpcAPI.html). You'll see there that `setUser` is not listed, but find `addAccount`, which can create new users. So this code works:

```
import os

from eulexistdb.db import ExistDB

password = os.environ["PASS"]
db = ExistDB("http://localhost:8088/", "admin",
             password, timeout=None, keep_alive=True)
db.server.addAccount("foo", "foo", "", [], True, 0022, {})
```

I actually recommend looking at the code of [`RpcConnection`](https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/eXist-2.2/src/org/exist/xmlrpc/RpcConnection.java), which implements `RpcApi` because the API documentation says almost nothing about the format of the parameters required and about the behavior of the various methods. For instance `getGroup` returns a `null` (which becomes `None` in Python) when the requested group does not exist, but `getAccount` raises an exception if the account does not exist. Why? Who knows, but the documentation sure does not tell you this.

Comment: Please consider filing an issue for eXist-db at https://github.com/exist-db/exist.